# Initializing a Graphics variable

Tags: java, graphics, initialization

How do you initialize a Graphics variable?

I tried `Graphics g = new Graphics()` and `Graphics g;` but it says it cannot be instantiated. I need to pass `Graphics g` from one method to another so I can't just call it from the argument. Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;

public class testApp extends JApplet 
{
    public void init() 
    {
    this.add(new RandomCardsPanel());
    }

public RandomCardsPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public Image card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11, card12, card13;
    public Image card14, card15, card16, card17, card18, card19, card20, card21, card22, card23, card24, card25, card26;
    public Image card27, card28, card29, card30, card31, card32, card33, card34, card35, card36, card37, card38, card39;
    public Image card40, card41, card42, card43, card44, card45, card46, card47, card48, card49, card50, card51, card52;

    public RandomCardsPanel() 
    {
        Image[] card = new Image[52];

        card[0] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c1.gif" );
        card[1] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c2.gif" );
        card[2] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c3.gif" );
        card[3] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c4.gif" );
        card[4] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c5.gif" );
        card[5] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c6.gif" );
        card[6] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c7.gif" );
        card[7] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c8.gif" );
        card[8] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c9.gif" );
        card[9] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c10.gif" );
        card[10] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "cj.gif" );
        card[11] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "cq.gif" );
        card[12] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "ck.gif" );
        card[13] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d1.gif" );
        card[14] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d2.gif" );
        card[15] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d3.gif" );
        card[16] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d4.gif" );
        card[17] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d5.gif" );
        card[18] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d6.gif" );
        card[19] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d7.gif" );
        card[20] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d8.gif" );
        card[21] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d9.gif" );
        card[22] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "d10.gif" );
        card[23] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "dj.gif" );
        card[24] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "dq.gif" );
        card[25] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "dk.gif" );
        card[26] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h1.gif" );
        card[27] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h2.gif" );
        card[28] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h3.gif" );
        card[29] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h4.gif" );
        card[30] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h5.gif" );
        card[31] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h6.gif" );
        card[32] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h7.gif" );
        card[33] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h8.gif" );
        card[34] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h9.gif" );
        card[35] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "h10.gif" );
        card[36] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "hj.gif" );
        card[37] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "hq.gif" );
        card[38] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "hk.gif" );
        card[39] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s1.gif" );
        card[40] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s2.gif" );
        card[41] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s3.gif" );
        card[42] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s4.gif" );
        card[43] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s5.gif" );
        card[44] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s6.gif" );
        card[45] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s7.gif" );
        card[46] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s8.gif" );
        card[47] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s9.gif" );
        card[48] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "s10.gif" );
        card[49] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "sj.gif" );
        card[50] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "sq.gif" );
        card[51] = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "sk.gif" );

        String cardNumber; 
        double cardRandom;
        int cardRandomNumber;
        public int[] ranNum = new int[10];
        Random ran = new Random();


        for (int number = 0; number <=  9; )
        {
            cardRandom = ran.nextInt(52) + 1;
            cardRandomNumber = (int)Math.round( cardRandom );

            if ( cardRandomNumber > 0 && cardRandomNumber <= 52 )
            { 
                ranNum[number] = cardRandomNumber;
                number++;
            }
        }   
    }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        setBackground( Color.green );
        g.drawImage( cards[ranNum[0]], 10, 10, this);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do any components appear on top of what you are wanting to paint?  If not, it is simpler to use a `BufferedImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you don't need to initialize a `Graphics` variable since most painting should be done in a components `paintComponent()` method. (And you can't do `Graphics g = new Graphics();` because `Graphics` is an abstract class.) Usually I will create a class which extends `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent()` method to do my custom painting. From there, I can pass the `Graphics` reference to any other methods that need it.

Try this out. Of course, I am talking at a pretty abstract level. Let us know what you figure out from these tips and we'll work from there.

**Edit:**

`JComponent` declares an abstract method [`paintComponent(Graphics g)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29). If you want to provide your own implementation, you *must* match this method signature exactly. That means you are only allowed *one* parameter, namely a `Graphics` object.

You are free to create a `paintComponent()` method with more arguments, but since the method signature doesn't match, it will not be called automatically on the Event Dispatch Thread when the operating system decides your Applet needs to be repainted.

With that said, you don't have to extend `JPanel` in order to get this to work. You can extend any class which in turn has `JComponent` as an ancestor. In your particular case, `JPanel` seems like the best option. I suggest that you refactor your code as follows:

In RandomCards.java

```
public RandomCards extends JApplet {
    public void init() {
        this.add(new RandomCardsPanel();
    }
}
```

In RandomCardsPanel.java

```
public RandomCardsPanel extends JPanel {
    // Put private member variables here

    public RandomCardsPanel() {
      // Put code from your current init() method here
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // Put your custom painting code here, including setting the background color and drawing the card images
    }
}
```

I have a few further suggestions, if you don't mind:

1. Notice that I am extending `JApplet` rather than `Applet`. This is the preferred class. `Applet` is still around for backwards-compatibility with AWT. Modern Java applets use `JApplet` and Swing instead.
2. When you indent code, use spaces rather than tabs. Tabs are displayed in a system-dependent manner. This means that if you view your code in another editor or on another computer, tab-formatted code may not appear the way you intended. In particular, you can see that this website does not format your code properly. Most text editors have a setting to replace tabs with spaces. I strongly suggest that you find out how to do this with yours.
3. When you find yourself using variable names that only differ with a number suffix (e.g. `Image card1, card2, card3, card4, card5`, etc.), you should use an array instead.
4. You *are* using an array inside the `init()` method. However, you have declared it as a local variable. This means that none of your other methods can see the `card` array you declared here. You should declare this as a member variable instead of the `card1, card2, card3`, etc. variables. The same goes for any other variables you need to use in your `paintComponent()` method since it can only have a single `Graphics g` parameter.
5. You do not need to call `paintComponent()` explicitly. In fact, you *should not* call it expicitly. The system will call this method whenever it is appropriate.

I hope this helps to clarify a few points. Good luck with your Java experience. Let us know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Good approach, nicely explained.  Another way to get direct control of a graphics instance is to paint in a `BufferedImage` (and display it in a label).

Comment: Would you mind showing an example please? I think I understand what your saying but I want to confirm.

Comment: @AlbertDong I would prefer that you post code that shows what you understand. I will be more than happy and willing to help you from there. You can either edit your original question here or post a new complete question, whichever you think is more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Had computer problems and wasn't able to get it working until yesterday. I edited my original code and replaced paint w/ paintComponent(). I'm unsure of what you mean by custom painting however. Do I need to extend my class with JPanel in order to use paintComponent()?

Comment: @AlbertDong I don't know if SO notifies you of my edit automatically. This comment will surely get your attention, though. ;-)

Comment: @Code-Guru Great post. it was very helpful. Sorry but I got to bother you some more. I have two questions regarding your format. When following your outline, I got an <identifier> expected error on line 15 ( public RandomCardsPanel extends JPanel ). In line 22, public RandomCardsPanel(), It says invalid method declaration and a return type is required. I've edited my original post to my updated code. Help concerning these two methods is appreciated! :)

Comment: @AlbertDong Your curly braces are foobar. To help, I suggest that you separate your code into two files: TestApp.java and RandomCardsPanel.java which each contain the class given by the file name. Once you have done this, be sure that your curly braces all match up. Also notice that I use "TestApp" rather than "testApp". Java convention is to start class names with uppercase. The class name and file name must match exactly, including case.

Comment: @AlbertDong I also strongly urge you to use spaces instead of tabs, as I mentioned in my answer above. In fact, "strongly urge" doesn't quite convey my opinion of the issue strongly enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Well there are two issues here :**

```
Graphics g1;
a.paint(g1);
```

And you are getting the error that G1 is not initialized. That's because the variable g1 is never set to anything, and that causes a compile error. To get the code to compile, you would need to, at the very least do this:

```
Graphics g1 = null;
a.paint(g1);
```

However, that obviously won't help you out too much. You'll get a NullPointerException when you try to run your code. In order to actually cause your graphics to draw you need to this:

```
So1 a=new So1();
Graphics g1 = So1.getGraphics();
a.paint(g1);
```

**Eg:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class So1 extends Applet{

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("hello",40,30);
    }

    public static void main(String ad[])
    {

        JFrame jp1 = new JFrame();
        So1 a=new So1 ();
        jp1.getContentPane().add(a, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp1.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        jp1.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Now notice, we don't actually call the paint() function ourselves. That's handled by the awt, which actually picks the graphics context, and calls our paint function for us. If you want, though, you can pass in any graphics object you want and ask it to draw on to that. (so if you want to draw your component onto an image, you can do it)

Comment: What do you mean by So1? Is it an instance variable?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of Java [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class is abstract so you can't instantiate it .

Comment: While technically an answer to the question, I prefer the answers that anticipate what the OP is trying to achieve, and explain how. +1 for the link.